# Do I need to dispose BLoC streams if they aren't assigned to a variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Say I directly call .listen on a bloc. I have no reference to the stream, which means I cannot call .cancel on it. Does this stream ever get cancelled automatically?

In my case it is not in a widget it's in a data model. The data model should be disposed of when it goes out of scope, but I'm worried this kind of stream will never get cancelled and live until the app is killed:

```
bloc.state.listen((state) {
  if (state is MyState) {
    dispatch(MyEvent());
  }
});
```

Note that my IDE does not give a warning about the stream not being cancelled. However when I do this:

```
StreamSubscription myStream; // IDE gives underline and warning

myStream = bloc.state.listen((state) {
  if (state is MyState) {
    dispatch(MyEvent());
  }
});
```

My IDE gives a warning to cancel my streams if I don't call .cancel somewhere. I do not get an IDE warning to cancel my streams in the first example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscription is the same in the first and second case.

If your data model persists during the whole life cycle of your app, you are fine.

Otherwise, you should assign the `StreamSubscription` to a variable and cancel this stream subscription once you dispose the data model, otherwise your listener will never be disposed and called even after you disposed your data model.

If you use that data model class in a widget, it should be a `StatefulWidget` and you would cancel your stream subscription in the [`State.dipose` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html).